# Closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closure of some countable subset

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ . How can I show that $A$ = closure of $B$ where $B$ is countable ? 
Thanks for any help .

Comment: I wonder if this is true without choice? All arguments supplied used it, but since we're dealing with closed subsets of ${\bf R}^n$, so relatively tame animals, it looks like it could be possible to somehow do without it...

Comment: In particular, if it was impossible, it would imply that we would have completely metrizable, second countable spaces that are not separable. That would be extremely counterintuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $p\in\Bbb R^n$ and $r>0$ let $B(p,r)=\{x\in\Bbb R^n:d(p,x)<r\}$, where $d(p,x)$ is the usual Euclidean distance in between $p$ and $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$. Let $\mathscr{B}=\{B(p,r):p\in\Bbb Q^n\text{ and }r\in\Bbb Q^+\}$, where $\Bbb Q^+$ is the set of positive rationals. $\mathscr{B}$ is a countable family of open sets in $\Bbb R^n$. Let $\mathscr{B}_0=\{B\in\mathscr{B}:B\cap A\ne\varnothing\}$.

For each $B\in\mathscr{B}_0$ choose a point $x_B\in B\cap A$, and let $D=\{x_B:B\in\mathscr{B}_0\}$; clearly $D$ is a countable subset of $A$. I leave it to you to prove that $\operatorname{cl}D=A$; it’s not hard, but I’ll add more explanation if you need it.

(There is in general no way to specify exactly how the points $x_B$ are chosen, so in general this argument requires the [axiom of choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice).)

**Added:** To show that $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}D$, let $x$ be any point of $A$. For any $\epsilon>0$ there are an $r\in\Bbb Q^+$ and a $p\in\Bbb Q^n$ such that $r<\epsilon/2$ and $p\in B(x,r)$. Then $B(p,r)\in\mathscr{B}$, and $x\in A\cap B(p,r)\ne\varnothing$, so $B(p,r)\in\mathscr{B}_0$, and $x_{B(p,r)}\in D\cap B(p,r)$. Finally, $d(x_{B(p,r)},x)\le d(x_{B(p,r)},p)+d(p,x)<2r<\epsilon$, so $x_{B(p,r)}\in D\cap B(x,\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this shows that $x\in\operatorname{cl}D$, and since $x\in A$ was arbitrary, it shows that $A\subseteq\operatorname{cl}D$.

Comment: Can you please show that A is a subset of closure of D?

Comment: @Ricky: Done; see if that helps.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Is $\mathscr{B}_0$ non-empty ?

Comment: @user123733: Of course, unless $A$ is empty. $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology, so every point of $\Bbb R^n$ is in infinitely many members of $\mathscr{B}$.

Answer (score 4):

The space $\mathbb R^n$ has a countable [base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28topology%29), i.e. it is a [second countable space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space).
E.g., the balls with rational diameters and centers having rational coordinates can be taken as a such base.

If $A=\emptyset$, you can take $B=\emptyset$. So let us assume from now on that $A$ is non-empty.

If you take any countable basis
$$\mathcal B=\{B_n; n\in\mathbb N\}.$$

Now for each $n$ you take $b_n$ as an arbitrary element of $A\cap B_n$, if $A\cap B_n$ is non-empty.

If $A\cap B_n=\emptyset$, you can choose $b_n$ as an arbitrary element of $A$.

The set $B=\{b_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$ fulfills the condition $\overline B=A$.

- Since $B\subseteq A$ and $A$ is closed, we have $\overline B\subseteq A$.
- If an element $x$ belongs to $A$ then for every basic neighborhood $B_n\ni x$ of $x$ we have $B_n\cap A\ne\emptyset$. This implies that $b_n\in B_n$. Therefore every neighborhood of $x$ contains an element of the set $B=\{b_n; n\in\mathbb N\}$; which means that $x\in\overline B$.

---

Notice, that we have used [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice) since we have chosen one element $b_n$ from each non-empty $A\cap B_n$.

---

The above proof is almost identical to the usual proof of the fact that
[Second-Countable Space is Separable](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Second-Countable_Space_is_Separable).

Comment: A subspace of a second countable metric space is second countable and metrizable. Since for metrizable spaces, second countable is equivalent to being separable (having countable dense subset) , we have that any subspace of a second countable metric space is separable. So if $A$ is a closed subspace of a second countable metric space $X$, then there is a countable  subset $B$ of $A$ such that  $A=cl_A (B)=\overline {B} \cap A$, where $cl_A (B)$ denotes the closure of $B$ in $A$. But $A$ is closed in $X$, and $B \subseteq A$, so $A=\overline {B} \cap A=\overline {B} $

Comment: @users I'd guess your comment could probably be posted as an answer.

Comment: I have just done that ...

Answer (score 2):

For each of the countably many intervals $[a,b]$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q^n$ select a single point of $[a,b]\cap A$ (if there is one).
Then if $x\in A$ and $\varepsilon>0$, find $a,b\in \mathbb Q$ with $x\in [a,b]\subset B(x,\varepsilon)$ and observe that the point chosen $\in[a,b]\cap A$ (which may be $x$ itself) has distance $<\varepsilon$ from $x$.

The above construction uses the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your help

Answer (score 0):

A subspace of a second countable metric space is second countable and metrizable. Since for metrizable spaces, second countable is equivalent to being separable (having countable dense subset) , we have that any subspace of a second countable metric space is separable. So if $A$ is a closed subset of a second countable metric space $X$, then $A$ is separable, hence there is a countable subset $B$ of $A$ such that  $A=cl_A (B)=\overline{B} \cap A$, where $cl_A(B)$ is the closure of $B$ in $A$ and $\overline B, \overline A$ are closure of $B,A$ in $X$ etc. But $B \subseteq A$ and $A$ is closed in $X$, so $\overline B \subseteq A$. Thus $A=\overline{B} \cap A=\overline B$, where $B$ is a countable subset of $A$.

Now apply the previous argument with $X=\mathbb R^n$.