# Probability measure with predefined support

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $I$ be an index set, possibly uncountable, and $U_\iota\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be closed for $\iota\in I$. Does there always exist a Borel probability measure $\mu$ such that $\text{supp}(\mu)=\bigcup_{\iota\in I} U_\iota$, where $\text{supp}(\mu)$ is the support of $\mu$, i.e. the smallest closed set $A$ such that $\mu(A^c)=0$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course not. The infinite union of closed sets is generally not closed. It might even fail to be Borel. Let $N\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$ be non-Borel, let $I=N$ and let $U_i=\{i\}$. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i=N$.

But for every closed set $C\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$, there is a probability measure $\mu$ with support $C$. Just pick a countable subset $D\subseteq C$ [such that $C$ is the closure of $D$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192701/closed-set-in-mathbb-rn-is-closure-of-some-countable-subset). If $D$ is finite, let $\mu$ be the uniform distribution on $D$. If $D$ is infinite, write it as $\{d_1,d_2,d_3,\ldots\}$ and let $\mu$ be the discrete probability measure that puts probability $1/2^n$ on the point $d_n$.