# Probability measure on a given measurable set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $A$ be a compact metric space,
and $E\subset A$ be a Borel measurable set. Does there exist a  finite positive measure $\mu$ on the Borel sets of $A$ such that $\mu(E)>0$ and $\mu(A\setminus E)=0$?

---

The question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208305/probability-measure-with-predefined-support), except that we don't ask $E$ to be the support of $\mu$.

Comment: Certainly not if $E=\emptyset$, but given any $y\in E$ there's $\mu:\mathcal P(A)\to \{0,1\}$, $\mu(X)=\begin{cases} 1&\text{if }y\in X\\ 0&\text{if }y\notin X\end{cases}$.

Comment: Thank you for such a simple and nice observation.